# ReactJs/NextJS - automatic redirect after 5 seconds to another page

Tags: reactjs, next.js

- I am creating welcome page which should appear right after customer is logged in and this page should automatically redirect customer to another page after 5 seconds. I tried to use setState with default value of 5 seconds and then using setInterval of 1000ms, decrease it by 1 and when it comes to 0, redirect customer.

**Console.log() always returns 5**, so basically on frontend I always see this sentence:
Welcome, you have successfully logged in, you will be redirected in.. 4

Looks like that because setRedirectSeconds() is asynchronous, it wont update state right at the moment and whenever my setInterval function starts again, redirectSeconds will still be 5 each time.

How to fix that?

Here is my code:

```
const Welcome: NextPage = (): ReactElement => {
const [redirectSeconds, setRedirectSeconds] = useState<number>(5);
const router = useRouter();
const query = router.query;

useEffect(() => {
    if (query?.redirect) {
        setTimeout(() => {
            const interval = setInterval(() => {
                console.log(redirectSeconds);
                if (redirectSeconds > 0) {
                    setRedirectSeconds(redirectSeconds - 1);
                } else {
                    clearInterval(interval);
                    router.push(query.redirect.toString());
                }
            }, 1000)
        }, 1000);
    }
}, []);

return (
        <div>
            Welcome, you have successfully logged in, you will be redirected in.. {redirectSeconds}
        </div>
);
};

export default Welcome;
```

Comment: I have found this great article https://thewebdev.info/2021/02/03/how-to-fix-a-state-that-is-not-updating-when-using-react-state-hook-in-setinterval/ which updates my state and decrease it by 1 each second and shows it on frontend but the problem is that console still logs always 5 and redirect doesnt happen

Answer (score 7):

Here is how I adjusted it and now it works fine:

- I have removed setInterval and added dependancy to useEffect function. And I have added timeout of 1000ms before decreasing redirectSeconds.

  ```
   useEffect(() => {
   if (query?.redirect) {
       if (redirectSeconds == 0) {
           router.push(query.redirect.toString());
           return;
       }

       setTimeout(() => {
           console.log(redirectSeconds);
           setRedirectSeconds((redirectSeconds) => redirectSeconds - 1);
       }, 1000)
   }
  }, [redirectSeconds]);
  ```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the below custom hook to achieve this functionality.

```
import { useRouter } from 'next/router';
import { useEffect, useState } from 'react';

export default function useRedirectAfterSomeSeconds(redirectTo, seconds = 5) {
  const [secondsRemaining, setSecondsRemaining] = useState(seconds);
  const router = useRouter();

  useEffect(() => {
    if (secondsRemaining === 0) router.push('/');

    const timer = setTimeout(() => {
      setSecondsRemaining((prevSecondsRemaining) => prevSecondsRemaining - 1);
      if (secondsRemaining === 1) router.push(redirectTo);
    }, 1000);

    return () => {
      clearInterval(timer);
    };
  }, [router, secondsRemaining, redirectTo]);

  return { secondsRemaining };
}
```

Usage example:

```
import Head from 'next/head';
import useRedirectAfterSomeSeconds from '../hooks/useRedirectAfterSomeSeconds';

export default function ErrorPage() {
  const { secondsRemaining } = useRedirectAfterSomeSeconds('/', 5);

  return (
    <>
      <Head>
        <title>Page not found - redirecting in 5 seconds</title>
      </Head>
      <main>
        <h1>404</h1>
        <p>
          This page cannot be found. Redirecting to homepage in
          {secondsRemaining} {secondsRemaining > 1 ? 'seconds' : 'second'}.
        </p>
      </main>
    </>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Set a top level state variable. when it hits 0, redirect the user

```
  import { useNavigate } from "react-router-dom";

  const [count, setCount] = useState(5);
```

Inside useEffect write a `setInterval` to decrease count by 1 after 1000ms

```
const navigate = useNavigate();
useEffect(()=>{
   // each second count=count-1
   const interval=setTimeInterval(()=>{
            setCount((updatedCount)=>updatedCcount-1)
        },1000)
    // if count===0 redirect

    count==0 && navigate(`/${query.redirect.toString()}`)

    // always clear the timeers in return function
    return ()=>{
          clearIntercal(interval)
    }

},[count,navigate])
```

then write the message.

```
     p>
      This page cannot be found. Redirecting to homepage in
      {count} {count > 1 ? 'seconds' : 'second'}.
    </p>
```